# How to use EditorFor to save changes to the Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a view like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.MyClass>
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
<form asp-action="Update">
     <table class="table">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsAvailable)
                </th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             @foreach (var item in Model)
             {
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.IsAvailable)
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             }
       </tbody>
   </table>
   <div>
       <a href=@Url.Action("SaveChanges", "Product", new {productList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model) })> Save changes</a>
   </div>
</form>
```

where SaveChanges looks like this:

```
[HttpGet] // Perhaps it should be HttpPost here, but if I change it to that nothing happens when I run the program after clicking the "Save changes" link
public ActionResult SaveChanges(string productList)
{
     List<MyClass> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(productList);
     // Here I continue with SqlCommand to later make an UPDATE to a database changing the value of IsAvailable which is the only adjustable value in my view
}
```

My issue is that when I run the program and I change IsAvailable (which is a bool) from `false` to `true` in my view and press "Save Changes", the model does not change, i.e. productList still has the value False for IsAvailable for that particular product.

Does anybody have an idea as to why? From my understanding if I have a  and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model information is not updated when you send the model to the action with the link. And the same initial amount is sent.

The changes you make to the model fields are only in the html controls and have nothing to do with the model. The model is updated when you post the form information.

*I submitted the form to jQuery in the following code*

**in view**

```
@model List<Namespace.MyClass>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
     <table class="table">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Product)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().IsAvailable)
                </th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Product)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].IsAvailable)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
       </tbody>
   </table>
   <div>
       @Html.ActionLink("Save changes", "", null, new { @id = "submit"})
   </div>
}

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
     
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            document.forms[0].submit();
            return false;
        });

    </script>
}
```

**action in controller**

```
[HttpPost] // Perhaps it should be HttpPost here, but if I change it to that nothing happens when I run the program after clicking the "Save changes" link
public ActionResult SaveChanges(IEnumerable<MyClass> products)
{        
   // Here I continue with SqlCommand to later make an UPDATE to a database changing the value of IsAvailable which is the only adjustable value in my view
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an elaborate answer! I've tried to apply the code you supplied but I ran into some issues. I've read some forums where someone said that ActionLink is only used with HttpGet. I therefore changed action link to be `<input type="submit" value="Save changes" />` and the script to become `$(document).on("click","type='submit']",function (){ document.forms[0].submit(); return false; });` which now works with HttpPost. I can pass my List<MyClass> to the SaveChanges ActionResult, however all the attributes are null. I get a list of 10 items though which is what what to be expected.

Comment: The code I entered in the reply posts the form in JavaScript. Regardless of whether ActionLink is used. You can use the button instead and delete the script.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It seems to be working now! I've misunderstood my form. I thought that if I have, say, Product as `DisplayNameFor`, and IsAvailable as `EditorFor` I'd pass both Product and IsAvailable to my controller, with the difference that Product could not be altered (as it does not use an edit template). However when I look now, I can see that IsAvailable has been passed, but not Product. So after lunch I'm going to investigate if I can make `EditorFor` for Product as well, but hidden or non-edible.

Comment: If the Product is a class, use it as @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].Product.Name) and ...

Comment: I'll look into it after lunch, but won't that give the user the opportunity to update Product? For clarification Product is the Primary Key for the database. So I cannot allow ProductName to be edited. However I still need it in the SaveChanges views so I can use an UPDATE on the SQL table with the new value of IsAvailable.

Comment: Define the main key for the product table and do not change the key. Then easily edit the product name.